# 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown when Exporting Data in Excel from .NET code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, export

I have a code to debug where I am attempting to export data in Excel. It works fine for smaller data but when data size increases to several thousands, I get 'Out of Memory exception'. My application is running on IIS 6.0. Any recommendations?

PS: The process usually fails when it takes more than 1.2 GB of memory (looking at the Task Manager)

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
  If (IsExportToCSV) Then
  Response.Clear()
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

        Response.ContentType = "a"
        'Remove the charset from the Content-Type header.
        Response.Charset = ""
        'Turn off the view state.
        Page.EnableViewState = False
        Dim tw As System.IO.StringWriter
        tw = New System.IO.StringWriter
        Dim hw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(tw)
        'Get the HTML for the control.
        Me.GridView1.AllowPaging = False
        Me.GridView1.DataBind()
        Me.GridView1.EnableViewState = False
        Me.GridView1.AutoGenerateEditButton = False
        Me.GridView1.RenderControl(hw)
        Response.Write(tw.ToString)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()

    Else
        MyBase.Render(writer)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How large is your GridView's data source?

Comment: It works fine when it is less than 10,000. It is failing when record count goes up. I have tested it for 60,000 and above it fails there.

Answer (score 4):

Perfect Solution!

I've been fighting this one for a while and the solution is so simple: Don't build a string to pass to response write as the string exist in memory, instead put each line directly into the response using multiple Response.Write calls

example for DataTable converted to HTML table and being sent to client as excel...

```
string contentType = "Reports.xls";
string fileName = "application/msexcel";

Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = contentType;
string attachment = string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", fileName);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition: ", attachment);
byte[] preamble = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble();
Response.BinaryWrite(preamble);

string strFontSize = "12";

Response.Write("<html xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" \r\n xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" \r\n xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">");
Response.Write(@"<head>");
Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1252\">");
Response.Write("<meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>");
Response.Write("<meta name=Generator content=\"Microsoft Excel 11\">");
Response.Write(@"</head>");
Response.Write(@"<body>");

Response.Write(@"<table style='width: 100%; font-size:" + strFontSize + ";' border='1'>");

foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        Response.Write(@"<td><b>" + column.ColumnName + "</b></td>");
    }
Response.Write(@"</tr>");

int intCell = 0;
string strCell = "";
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        intCell = 0;
        Response.Write(@"<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            strCell = row.ItemArray[dt.Columns[column.ColumnName].Ordinal].ToString().Trim();
            Response.Write(@"<td>" + strCell + "</td>");
        }
        Response.Write(@"</tr>");
    }
Response.Write(@"</table>");
Response.Write(@"</body>");
Response.Write(@"</html>");
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

write each line directly info the response stream instead of passing trough the StringWriter

Comment: Thanks, Felice. Could you provide me an example?